# EasyPHP Devserver doesn't start

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, easyphp-devserver

image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpDuM.png

I just installed EasyPHP Devserver, it would enable you to access PHPmyAdmin clicking on module at the bottom of the page, the problem is that in order to start those modules You must start the Database and HTTP before.
Http works, but when I click on Database it doesn't do nothing.

I've also tried to use Xampp, but neither this works, maybe my pc has some problem with virtual ports...

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it's not a virtual ports problem !

I started the development with easyphp, but after that I preferred to use [WampServer](https://www.wampserver.com), and even more linux debian.

if you want to work with wamp, don't forget to install Visual Studio :)